# C# XML Node Works with Element But Not with Elelments

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

i want to get the child nodes of suras in the following xml data;

```
<suras alias="chapters">
    <sura index="1" ayas="7" start="0" name="الفاتحة" tname="Al-Faatiha" ename="The Opening" type="Meccan" order="5" rukus="1" />
    <sura index="2" ayas="286" start="7" name="البقرة" tname="Al-Baqara" ename="The Cow" type="Medinan" order="87" rukus="40" />
    <sura index="3" ayas="200" start="293" name="آل عمران" tname="Aal-i-Imraan" ename="The Family of Imraan" type="Medinan" order="89" rukus="20" />
    <sura index="4" ayas="176" start="493" name="النساء" tname="An-Nisaa" ename="The Women" type="Medinan" order="92" rukus="24" />
    <sura index="5" ayas="120" start="669" name="المائدة" tname="Al-Maaida" ename="The Table" type="Medinan" order="112" rukus="16" />
</suras>
```

The suras node is comming fine but when i try to access the `sura` node, i can't get it as an `Elements` of `suras`;

[image]
as you can see if i debug the parent i.e **suras** node, i can clearly see the first and last node correctly. But when i try to query its Elements or Decendents, i dont' get anything. Check the following screen shot;
[image]
Similarly, if i change my code to `Element("sura")` instead of `Elements("sura")`, then it only shows first node check this;
[image]
So, my question is, **Why i am not getting the child nodes i.e surah?**

Comment: It's *really* hard to see what's going on with just a debugger screen capture... and "I can't get it" doesn't really explain it well either. Are you seeing problems outside the debugger? It's entirely possible this is just a debugger visualization issue - but if it's not, please produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, with console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually worked, you just can't see it that way. Try to iterate through `Elements("suras")` and you'll get the result just fine :

```
....
var test2 = test.Elements("sura");
foreach (XElement sura in test2)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sura.ToString())
    //or print to VS output window :
    //Debug.WriteLine(sura.ToString());
}
```

Or materialize the query to be able to see the actual result without looping, by calling `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` :

```
var test2 = test.Elements("sura").ToList();
```

Comment: yes i couldn't get the result using visual studio debugging experience, i actually should have looped through it. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not iterating through the Child Nodes.

Refer the below codes:

```
            var myDoc = new XmlDocument();
            myDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));

            // Get All Suras Elements
            var AllSuras = myDoc.GetElementsByTagName("suras");

            // For now Select the First item in the All Suras
            var Sura = AllSuras[0].ChildNodes;

            foreach (XmlNode surah in Sura)
            {
                var index = surah.Attributes["index"];
                var ayas = surah.Attributes["ayas"];
                var start = surah.Attributes["start"];
                var name = surah.Attributes["name"];
                var tname = surah.Attributes["tname"];
                var ename = surah.Attributes["ename"];
                var type = surah.Attributes["type"];
                var order = surah.Attributes["order"];
                var rukus = surah.Attributes["rukus"];
            }
```

Hope this helps!